# How to compute $y = z\left(\frac {-2\ln r^2} {r^2}\right) $ in Box–Muller transform?

Tags: normal-distribution, partial-derivative

In PRML chapter 11, the book using Box-Muller method to generate Gaussian distribution.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform),

$P(y_1,y_2) = \int\int\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}dy_1dy_2 = 1$

after some polar tansform, you can get cdf of R:

$P(R<=r)= \int^r_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}}{2\pi}rd\theta dr 
= \int^r_0 e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} r dr 
= 1 - e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$

adding uniform distribute variable $z\in (0,1)$ into the equation we have:

$P(R<=r)=1 - e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} $

But I cannot compute the equation of $y = z(\frac {-2\ln(r^2)} {r^2})^{1/2}$

The paragraph discribe as follow:
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's no reason you should be interested in $\sqrt{-2\ln(r^2)}$, which can be either real if $r<1$ or imaginary if $r>1$.

Comment: @J.G. that'show far I can get. so where should I work on to reach the conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRML actually describes an alternative, the Marsaglia polar method. You've computed the distribution of the standard Box-Muller method's radial variable, with support $[0,\,\infty)$. But in Marsaglia, a different radial variablre satisfies $R^2\sim U(0,\,1)$. The angle $\Theta$ in $Z_1=R\cos\Theta,\,Z_2=R\sin\Theta$ is $U(0,\,2\pi)$. We have $Y_1=\color{red}{\sqrt{-2\ln Z_1}}\color{blue}{Z_1/R}$; the red factor is an inverse CDF converting $Z_1$ to a Box-Muller radius, while the blue factor is the cosine. Doing the same with $Z_2$ uses a sine, obtaining $Y_2$.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see now, $Y = sin\theta * r$. Thank you for your answer.